# using variable for PHP search

Tags: php, api

How do I use a variable entered in a text box to be the search for the TinySong api? I tried using some variables but to no avail. Here is what I tried:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 echo ' ',  htmlspecialchars($_POST['something']);
}
?>

<?php


require_once 'tinysong.php';

$api_key = 'MY API KEY';

$query = '$something ';


$tinysong = new Tinysong($api_key);


$result = $tinysong
            ->search($query)
            ->execute();


echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I don't understand why the text box's value isn't being queried. What do i have to change for it to work?? Thank You

Comment: I assume you changed "MY_API_KEY?"

Comment: Yea, LOL   Im jst not sure why the top code isn't working for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no variable `$something`. You have `$_POST['something']`, but unless `register_globals` is on (which it shouldn't be), you never populated `$something`. You therefore have nothing to query.

```
$query = $_POST['something'];
```

Incidentally, you've also used single quotes here, which won't cause the variable to be interpolated. Double quotes are needed for interpolation:

```
// This would have needed double quotes if it wasn't incorrect anyway...
$query = '$something ';

$query = "$something ";
```

Answer (score 3):

Presuming you've got register_globals disabled (I hope you have!) you'll need to use `$_POST["something"]` instead of `$something`.

Also, why `'$something'` - single quotes in PHP means that the contents of the string won't be parsed. You can't reference variables from within. Can't you just do something along the lines of:

```
$tinysong->search($_POST["something"])->execute();
```

If you were to use `'$something'`, the contents of the string will be `"$something"` - which I presume is not what you want.